# Gradle error "Java plugin is not compatible with android plugins"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to run my testng tests through gradle on Android studio. I have source code and tests placed in the gradle file using unitTest gradle feature. So to use the test task i have to apply java plugin but android studio is giving me an error saying "Java plugin is not compatible with android plugins". I know android and java plugins are not compatible with each other, but is there any solution for it? This is my build.gradle looks like

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies {
    // Android Support Library
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.8.7'
    androidTestCompile 'dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:2.44.0'
    androidTestCompile 'jaxen:jaxen:1.1.6'
    androidTestCompile 'io.appium:java-client:2.2.0'
}

test {

    useTestNG()
    //options.suites("src/androidTest/res/groups.xml")

}
```

Comment: Are you using an IDE? This looks like Android Studio

Comment: yes i am using android studio

Comment: Wow you answered before I could edit my comment

Comment: Ok but what why do you need java plugin?

Comment: I am using testng task "test" which requires java plugin. Without it, it says "test() method not found"

Comment: Maybe this will help?  http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support

Comment: Please tell me if it does so I can add it to answer; it should work as far as I know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works by changing the androidTestCompile to testCompile

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comments you don't need the Java plugin for testing; Android Studio already has built-in support for testing (as of 1.1). So I suggest you taking a look at the Android Studio testing support which you can find [here](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.htm). It is described very nicely how to install and use (with screenshots).